# Is there a discrete subset $M$ of $\mathbb{C}$ and an entire function $f$ such that $f(M)$ is not a discrete subset of $f(\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: complex-analysis

So I have been wondering the following

> Is there a discrete subset $M$ of $\mathbb{C}$ and an entire function $f$ such that $f(M)$ is not a discrete subset of $f(\mathbb{C})$?

The definition I am using is that a set $M$ is called a discrete subset of $N \subset \mathbb{C}$ iff for all $z \in N$ there exists an $r > 0$ such that $M \cup K_r(z) \subset \{z\}$.

I have had some ideas trying it with $M = \mathbb{N}$ but that hasn't worked out yet. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: $M = \mathbb{Z}$, $f = \sin$. More generally, for every entire transcendental function, we can find such $M$.

Comment: $M= \{ 2 \pi n + 1/n : n \in \Bbb{Z}^+ \}$ , $f= \sin$.